# Meteor Getting Dynamically Generated Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to get the values of some dynamically generated selects I am adding to a form. I think I am doing it correctly, but it only returns the first selects value.

Form Template:

```html
<form id="Dynamic" class="add-clients col s12 m10 offset-m1 white z-depth-1">
      <div class="row">
        <h4>Add a new company with company contacts.</h4>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">business</i>
          <input id="company_name" name="company_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="company_name">Company Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-placeholder row">
        <!--append contact select-->
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="add-contacts input-field col s12">
          {{> ContactSelect}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <button class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light" href="#" id="s">Save Company</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

The Dynamic Select Template:

```js
Template.ContactSelect.events({
  'click .add-select'(event){
    $( ".first-select .contact-selectBox" ).clone().appendTo( ".incoming-input" ).after('<a href="#" class="btn">Remove</a>');
  },
});
```

```html
<template name="ContactSelect">
  <div class="first-select input-field col s12">
    <select class="contact-selectBox browser-default">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      {{#each allContacts}}
        <option value="{{_id}}">{{fullname}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="incoming-input input-field col s12">

  </div>
  <div class="multiply-select col s12">
    <a class="add-select btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
  </div>
</template>
```

And Lastly the submit event for the form:

```js
Template.ClientAddNew.events({
  'submit .add-clients'(event, template){
    event.preventDefault();
    var selection = {};
    template.$("option:selected").each(function(index){
      selection["box"+index] = template.$("option:selected").attr("value");
    });
    console.log(selection);
  }
});
```

What I find odd is that when I replace `.attr("value")` with `.text()` it does add both selected options, but it concatinates them together.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a bad time trying to do what you're doing using the browser-default select.

Use an entirely HTML based select widget. Then, think about how you could mark `selected` reactively (consider a `{{selected}}` attribute inside your `{{#each allContacts}} ...` block. Then, if you want to manipulate the text of anything, manipulate it using the `allContacts` helper. For example:

```
<div class='select-widget'>
{{#each allContacts}}
    <div id='{{_id}}' class='select-widget-row {{#if selected}}selected{{/if}}'>
         {{fullname}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```